# Cannot add new Server to Server Explorer on Visual Studio

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

After upgrade to Visual Studio 2017 it not possible Add New Server to Server Explorer.

I get the error:

Server name "\SQLEXPRESS" could not be found. Make sure the server name is correct.

But I can add connection to specific database via connection string.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To add a link to a server in Server Explorer

1. Select Connect to Server on the Tools menu, or click the Connect to Server icon in Server Explorer.
   The Add Server dialog box opens. For more information, see Add Server Dialog Box.
2. In the Computer text box, enter the name or IP address of the
   server.

Try removing a link to a server from Server Explorer

1. In Server Explorer, expand the Servers node.
2. Right-click the server that is no longer needed.
3. Select Delete from the shortcut menu.
   There is no effect on the actual server. You are removing the link from your view.

Try reconnecting to a remote server as a different user

1. Delete any existing connections to the remote computer as the
   desired user.
   You cannot create multiple connections to a remote server as the same user of that computer. This includes NET USE connections.
2. Select Connect to Server from the Tools menu, or click the Connect
   to Server icon on the toolbar.
   The Add Server dialog box opens.
3. In the Computer box, enter the name or IP address of the server.
4. Select Connect using a different user name.
   The Connect As dialog box opens.
5. Enter a new user name and password.
6. In the Computer box, enter the name or IP address of the server.

Comment: Are added Event Logs, Message Queues, etc., but not the database server.

Comment: Well, I found that the connection to SQL Server and LocalDB are in SQL Server Object Explorer and not in Server Explorer.

Comment: @Taha Have you tried between different OSs such as Windows and Linux?